# $\int\frac{\tan^2 x-1}{\cos ^4 x}dx$

Tags: integration

$$\int\frac{\tan^2 x-1}{\cos ^4 x}dx$$

I know yhe answer:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int%7B%5Ctan%5E2+x-1%7D%5C%7B%5Ccos+%5E4+x%7D
but I don't know how solve it.

I need any hint.

Comment: $$\int\frac{\tan^2 x-1}{\cos ^4 x}dx
=\int(\tan^2 x-1)(\tan^2 x+1) d(\tan x)
$$

Comment: In these cases, [this](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) is often helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty standard: the starting integral can be rewritten as

\begin{align*}
&=\int \sec^2 x (\tan^2 x - 1) (\tan ^2 (x)+1)dx\\
&\text{make the substitution } u = \tan x \longrightarrow \dfrac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} = \sec^2 x \longrightarrow \mathrm{d} x = \dfrac{1}{\sec ^2 x}\mathrm{d}u\\
&= \int (u^2 -1) (u^2+1)du\\
&= \int (u^4 - 1 )du\\
&= \dfrac{u^5}{5} - u\\
&\text{revert the original substitution then we get the final expression}:\\
&\boxed{\int\frac{\tan^2 x-1}{\cos ^4 x}dx = \dfrac{\tan^ 5 x}{5} - \tan x + C}.
\end{align*}

where the only tools we used were the identities:
\begin{align}
&\cos x = \dfrac{1}{\sec x}\\
&\sec ^2 x = \tan ^2 x + 1
\end{align}